# open set containing diagonal in a compact Hausdorff space

Tags: general-topology

Suppose $X$ is a compact Hausdorff space. Say $x \in X$, and let $U$ be a nbhd of $x$. Then there is an open set $U' \subseteq X$ with $x \in U' \subseteq U$. I'm trying to understand why the following statement is true:

"There is an open set $V \subseteq X \times X$ containing the diagonal, such that if $x_{1} \in U'$ and $(x_{1},x_{2}) \in V$, then $x_{2} \in U$."

To get an open set, I suppose we could take the union of some open sets, each which contains an element of the diagonal, but then we don't have too much say over how these open sets behave. What's going on here? Thanks for any help.

Comment: I think the point is to construct $V$ in a manner that depends on $U'$ and $U$.  While $X\times X$ certainly is an open set containing the diagonal (and indeed every point!), it does not follow that if $x_1 \in U'$ and $(x_1,x_2) \in X\times X$, then $x_2 \in U$.

Comment: @DanielRust I don't think so, because if $U \neq X$, $X \times X$ could contain some $(x_{1},x_{2})$ where $x_{1} \in U'$ but $x_{2} \not\in U$.

Comment: There is something missing. For every neighbourhood $U$, you can choose an open $U'$ such that there is a $V$ with the desired properties. But not for every open $U' \subseteq U$ does there exist a $V$ with the desired properties. Quick example, $X = [-2,\,2]$, $x = 0$, $U' = U = (-1,\,1)$. At the boundary points, you get a violation. You must choose $U'$ so that $\overline{U'}$ is contained in the interior of $U$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose that the closure $\overline{U'}$ is contained in $U$. I think this is the missing piece.

Let $\{J_\alpha\}$ be an open cover of $X$. Replace each $J_\alpha$ by $J_\alpha\cap U$ and $J_\alpha\setminus \overline{U'}$ to obtain a new open cover $\{K_\alpha\}$. Then write $V = \bigcup_\alpha (K_\alpha\times K_\alpha)$.

As a union of open sets $V$ is open. It contains the diagonal since $\{K_\alpha\}$ covers $X$. If $(x_1,x_2)\in V$ with $x_1\in U'$, then each $K_\alpha$ for which $(x_1,x_2)\in K_\alpha\times K_\alpha$ has the form $K_\alpha = (J_\beta\cap U)$. So $x_2\in K_\alpha \subseteq U$.

I didn't use compactness here nor the Hausdorff property. Maybe there is an easier way?

Comment: Thanks @Andrew Poelstra. I'll keep this in mind for later.